# My data store in Debug database only

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have a visual studio windows form project.
I have a window to let user enter Document Information like

[image]
and after the user finishes .. I take these Information and store them in Document table in database

```
connectingString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccountingPro.Properties.Settings.DAccConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectingString);
con.Open();
String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.document (docnum, basicdate, userdate, doctype, amount, AccountNumber, accountname, discounttype, discountpercentage, amountafterdiscount, comments, posted) VALUES(@id, @BD, @UD, @DT, @Am, @anum, @aname, @disT, @disP, @aad, @notes, @de)";
command = new SqlCommand(query, con);
command.Parameters.Add("@id", this.ID);
command.Parameters.Add("@BD", this.Basic_Date);
command.Parameters.Add("@UD", this.User_Date);
command.Parameters.Add("@DT", this.Type_of_Doc);
command.Parameters.Add("@Am", this.Amount);
command.Parameters.Add("@anum", this.account_num);
command.Parameters.Add("@aname", this.account_name);
command.Parameters.Add("@disT", '0');
command.Parameters.Add("@disP", '0');
command.Parameters.Add("@aad", '0');
command.Parameters.Add("@notes", this.Notes);
 if(this.departure == false)
    command.Parameters.Add("@de", '0');
 else
    command.Parameters.Add("@de", '1');

 da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
 dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);
 da.Update(dt);

 con.Close();
```

the problem that these information store in database at just run time.
when I started new execution, I couldn't found the previous information like the table is empty

can you help me ??
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are inserting data to DB rather than retrieving, Don't use `SqlDataAdapter` use `ExecuteNonQuery` command:

```
...
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: yes, exactly, looks like if in the code he forgot add the `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: I tried this .. the same problem ... I enter 2 rows then i close visual studio and open it again .... the 2 rows were exists but when i tried to add more rows .. the 2 rows disappear and I just see the new rows

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're using a local .MDB file to store you're data and the file is getting overwritten when you build the project.

Change the **Copy to Output Directory** property to **Do Not Copy** to prevent the file from getting overwritten.  You can then either change your connnection string to point to the file in your project directory or manually copy to the "bin" folder when appropriate.

More tips on MSDN:

- [How to: Manage Local Data Files in Your Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx)
- [Local Data Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx)

Note:  I would also change to use `ExecuteNonQuery` like the other answers suggest rather than using `SqlDataAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to insert data in the database you have to use the ExecuteNonQuery method of the command object. It is also a good thing to dispose any IDisposable objects like the connection and the command object.

```
         string connectingString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccountingPro.Properties.Settings.DAccConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectingString))
        {
            con.Open();
            String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.document (docnum, basicdate, userdate, doctype, amount, AccountNumber, accountname, discounttype, discountpercentage, amountafterdiscount, comments, posted) VALUES(@id, @BD, @UD, @DT, @Am, @anum, @aname, @disT, @disP, @aad, @notes, @de)";
            using (var command = con.CreateCommand()) {
                command.Parameters.Add("@id", this.ID);
                command.Parameters.Add("@BD", this.Basic_Date);
                command.Parameters.Add("@UD", this.User_Date);
                command.Parameters.Add("@DT", this.Type_of_Doc);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Am", this.Amount);
                command.Parameters.Add("@anum", this.account_num);
                command.Parameters.Add("@aname", this.account_name);
                command.Parameters.Add("@disT", '0');
                command.Parameters.Add("@disP", '0');
                command.Parameters.Add("@aad", '0');
                command.Parameters.Add("@notes", this.Notes);
                if (this.departure == false)
                    command.Parameters.Add("@de", '0');
                else
                    command.Parameters.Add("@de", '1');

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I tried this .. the same problem ... I enter 2 rows then i close visual studio and open it again .... the 2 rows were exists but when i tried to add more rows .. the 2 rows disappear and the I just see the new rows

Comment: Look at the revised code again. Also make sure you do not catch an exception and handle it silently. You may have some problem with the SQL statement itself.

Comment: I tried this .. the same problem ... I enter 2 rows then i close visual studio and open it again .... the 2 rows were exists but when i tried to add more rows .. the 2 rows disappear and the I just see the new rows

Comment: Open Management Studio and look at the table itself. If the rows are there the problem is somewhere else in your code. May be the part where you are retrieving the records is not correct.